# Building an Advanced Search (text, tags, category, custom fields) - Getting the wrong SQL query

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search, advanced-custom-fields, pre-get-posts

I'm building an advanced search form, where I want to use the normal text field, tags,categories and also some custom fields.
I created a form with all the values and i created a url parameters to make it nicer and i use `pre_get_posts` to add the custom fields if it is needed... but the query is not what i expect and it is really weird in my opinion.

I will explain the steps that i did:

1) create a form (I skip this part)

2) make it nicer I build a url and i use the following code to rewrite and do it:

URL:
`"/cerca/text/$text/provincia/$provincia/comarca/$comarca/municipi/$municipi/filtres/$filtres/"`

Rewrite code

```
add_action('init', 'create_cerca_url_querystring_parameters');
function create_cerca_url_querystring_parameters()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^cerca\/text\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)\/provincia\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)\/comarca\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)\/municipi\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)\/filtres\/([a-zA-Z0-9-+,]+)\/?',
        'index.php?s=$matches[1]&provincia=$matches[2]&category_name=$matches[3]&municipi=$matches[4]&tag=$matches[5]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

3) post_get_post function

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query');
function advanced_search_query($query)
{
    if (! is_admin() && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query()) {

        //Get Parameteres
        //$text      = getSearchParameter('text');
        $provincia = getSearchParameter('provincia');
        $municipi  = getSearchParameter('municipi');

        //Configuration
        $query->set('post_type', array( 'post' ));
        $query->set('post_status', array( 'publish' ));

        if(!empty($provincia) && !empty($municipi)){

            $mainArray = array('relation' => 'OR');

            //Set Parameters

            $provArray = array(
                  'key'   => 'provincia',
                  'value' => $provincia,
                  'compare'    => 'LIKE'
                  );
            array_push($mainArray, $provArray);



            $municipiArray = array(
                'key'   => 'municipi',
                'value' => $municipi,
                'compare'    => 'LIKE'
                );
            array_push($mainArray, $municipiArray);


            $query->set('meta_query', $mainArray);

            var_dump($mainArray);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Return the given parameter value from the search URL
 */
function getSearchParameter($parametre, $decode=TRUE)
{
    $valueToReturn = '';
    $path  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $split = explode("/", $path);
    $key   = array_search($parametre, $split);
    if ($key > 0) {
        $value = $split[$key+1];
        $urlValues = array("text", "provincia", "comarca", "municipi", "filtres","none","");
        if (!in_array($value, $urlValues)) {
          if($decode){
            $valueToReturn = urldecode($value);
          }else{
            $valueToReturn = $value;
          }
        }
    }
    return $valueToReturn;
}
```

4) then in the search.php I print the query result using

```
<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>
```

And here is where my surprise arrive and i don't know the query look like that:

Query with municipi and provincia:

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE **1=1 AND ( 0 = 1 )** AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'provincia' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%barcelona%' ) OR ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'municipi' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%sant%' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 18

Another query with only text:
/cerca/text/test/provincia/none/comarca/none/municipi/none/filtres/none/

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 **AND ( 0 = 1 AND 0 = 1 )** AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%test%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%test%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%test%'))) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%test%' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 18

**Here goes my question:**

Does anyone know why i get this SQL ? if i remove the condition (0=1) then it works, but i don't know why it is there.
Am I doing something wrong ? I just want to filter by provincia and municipi if this parameters are set, any idea ?

**Inspired in the following posts:**

[How to use custom field to search for wordpress post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182385/how-to-use-custom-field-to-search-for-wordpress-post-type)

[Advanced search form with filters for custom taxonomies and custom fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38361/advanced-search-form-with-filters-for-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-fields)

[Custom search for custom post type, custom meta and search fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105696/custom-search-for-custom-post-type-custom-meta-and-search-fields)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I ran into something similar on another question recently, but I can't remember which one it was. I could reproduce it when using custom taxonomies in the query that weren't yet registered, or having non-existant slugs. Does your query have a tax_query? Can you share all query args for $wp_query?

Comment: You are completely right @janh2, I was sending a non existing taxonomie by error and this was causing this AND (0=1).

I changed and i created one for all the different combinations if a parameter is missing.. and it works perfectly! 

Do you know if there is a way to add the rewrite_rule dynamically ? because now i have like 10 rules or more.. because i have no clue how to do the regex if the $matches is empty...

Comment: Do you mean adding a rewrite rule that has only municipi, another that only has provincia etc and then their combinations or what are those 10 rules? In general, unless they annoy you, the speed should be irrelevant, regexps are crazy fast.

Comment: yes, I meant exactly what you said... only municipi, only provincia, only comarca, and all the combinations... it is a bit annoying to maintain.. it is working for now.. but I would like to know if there is a better solution or if it is possible to create the url string dynamically.

Comment: You'd have to go through all possible combinations of the elements and dynamically build the URLs and matches, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array) to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

I will post my solution and explain what was the problem and I hope that this post can help someone in the future.

As we talk in the small comments the problem, was that I was sending a non existing taxonomy by error and this was causing the AND (0=1).

To fix the whole problem I created a `add_rewrite_rule` for each case when I have parameter or not like the following example:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
   '^cerca/comarca/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)/?',
   'index.php?s=&category_name=$matches[1]',
   'top'
);

 add_rewrite_rule(
   '^cerca/municipi/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)/?',
   'index.php?s=&municipi=$matches[1]',
   'top'
);
   add_rewrite_rule(
   '^cerca/provincia/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)/?',
   'index.php?s=&provincia=$matches[1]',
   'top'
);
add_rewrite_rule(
   '^cerca/provincia/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)/comarca/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)/municipi/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)/?',
   'index.php?s=&provincia=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]&municipi=$matches[3]',
   'top'
);
```

....

Thanks to @janh2 for all the helpful comments.